# HTML interpreted in a different way on server

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following HTML  generated by javascript:

```
'    <section class="panel panel-default" style="padding-bottom: 0;">'+
'        <div class="text-center wrapper bg-light">'+
'            <div id="sparkline_'+id+'" class="sparkline inline" data-type="pie" data-height="165" data-slice-colors="'+colors+'"></div>'+
'                <div style="display: inline-block; width: 220px; height: 165px; vertical-align: top;">' +
'        <ul class="list-group no-radius">'+
'            <li class="list-group-item">'+
'                <span class="pull-right">'+data['stats']['average_score']+'</span>'+
'                <span class="label bg-Kultur pull-left">1</span>'+
'            Gennemsnitlig score </li>'+
'            <li class="list-group-item">'+
'                <span class="pull-right">'+data['stats']['average_modules_taken']+'</span>'+
'                Antal moduler taget <span class="label bg-salg  pull-left">2</span>'+
'            </li>'+
'            <li class="list-group-item">'+
'                <span class="pull-right">'+data['academy_completed']+'</span>'+
'                <span class="label bg-adfard  pull-left">'+data['academy_completed']+'</span>'+
'            Gennemførte akademier </li>'+
'        </ul>'+
'</div>'+
'            </div>'+
'        </div>'+
'        <ul class="list-group no-radius">'+
'            <li class="list-group-item">'+
'                <span class="pull-right">'+data['category']+'</span>'+
'                Beste kategori'+
'            </li>'+
'            <li class="list-group-item">'+
'                <span class="pull-right">'+data['type']['type_name']+ '</span>'+
 '   Beste modul type'+
'             </li>'+
'            <li class="list-group-item">'+
'                <span class=""><a href="#" class="btn btn-xs userView" onclick="viewUser('+id+',event)">Se mere</a></span>'+
'                <span class="label"></span>'+
'             </li>'+

'        </ul>'+
'    </section>'
```

When i run this on my local machine it results in the following:

[image: Local image]

However when i run the EXACT same code on my server i get the following:

[image: Server image]

Comment: html is not interpreted on the server in any way.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "on the server"? Do you mean a browser running on your server?

Comment: @JME i mean when i put my code online and view it on my website.

Comment: @MillaresRoo Well do you know what the problem might be? im not changing broswer or anything

Comment: What do you mean by 'run'? Running a piece of html is similar to running a Word document.

Comment: Have you made sure the CSS files are exactly the same on your server and locally?

Comment: What browser(s) are you testing in?

Comment: @MarcRasmussen it looks like a css problem. Maybe different versions of your css files.

Comment: I have checked all css and it is identical. i am using chrome as a browser

Comment: The bottom image looks slightly narrower than the top one. Maybe there are media queries in the css for different browser widths.

Comment: @Jme Your a genious thats it!

Comment: Glad to be of service! :-)